# Drag and drop not working using Highcharts-React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

I would like to add drag and drop functionality to a Highcharts `arearange` series (in the Y direction). As far as I can tell, I should put the configuration in [`series.arearange.dragDrop`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.arearange.dragDrop):

```js
// …

import Highcharts from "highcharts/highstock";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";

// …

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
  more(Highcharts);
}

// …

<HighchartsReact
  highcharts={Highcharts}
  constructorType={"chart"}
  options={{
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      text: ""
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2,
      shared: true
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime"
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: ""
      },
      min: 0
    },
    series: [
      // …
      {
        name: "Range",
        data: chartData.average_ranges,
        type: "arearange",
        dragDrop: {
          draggableY: true,
        },
        lineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: ":previous",
        color: "lightBlue",
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: 0,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      // …
    ]
  }}
/>
```

However, this doesn't make the points draggable. There are no errors in the console. Tested in Safari and Firefox.

I have also tried enabling [`plotOptions.arearange.dragDrop.draggableY`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.arearange.dragDrop.draggableY), but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import and initialize `draggable-points` module:

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import more from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import draggable from "highcharts/modules/draggable-points";

if (typeof Highcharts === "object") {
  more(Highcharts);
  draggable(Highcharts);
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-llomi

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#how-to-add-a-module